# How to abut a number next to a parameter in a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have in a Windows batch file named `doit.bat`

```
dir C:\%12\*.*
```

with the intent to pass a folder name to the batch file referenced with `%1` and list the folder `C:\<some_folder>2\*.*`.

So, I would like to run for the folder `C:\myfiles2` the command line `doit myfiles`.

But the batch file interprets `%12` as one argument reference and not `%1`.

How can I concatenate `%1` and the number `2` so the command works as desired?

Comment: what is the first argument when you use the script? You might need to dequote by using `%~1`

Comment: [Don't call it DOS if you're using Windows cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this failing - I guess I don't have enough context. I tried to recreate the problem, but the code above works for me.

However, you can force it to behave the way you want by assigning another variable to contain the value in `%1`, and then using that variable in your `DIR` command instead:

```
set MYDIR=%1
dir C:\%MYDIR%2\*.*
```

To figure out what's going on without this, you can watch the execution of your script with `echo on` enabled. It might help you track where it starts misbehaving.